Loading is not working when try to set Metadata from a API response in nextjs approuter
I have product details API, which have some meta data like title, description etc, when i call the API and set the metadata and show data in component, page not show untill API is not return the response but i want to show a loading page until the API call is not done.
here is my Page.js file
import React, { cache,Suspense } from "react";
import Details from "./details";
import { getLanguage } from "@/utils/get-language";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import API from "@/services/ApiService";
import { ApiEndPoint } from "@/services/ApiEndPoint";
const fetchDataById = cache(async (id) => {
  const selectedLanguage = getLanguage();
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Accept-Language": selectedLanguage ? selectedLanguage : "en",
      },
    };
    const response = await API.get(
      ApiEndPoint.getBookingbyDate + "/" + id,
      config
    ).then((res) => res.data);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    return null;
  }
});
async function getDataAndId(params) {
  const experienceId = params?.experience?.join("-")?.split("-")?.pop();
  if (!isNaN(experienceId)) {
    const data = await fetchDataById(experienceId);
    return { data };
  } else {
    const data = await fetchDataById(params?.experience);
    return { data };
  }
}
async function page({ params }) {
  const { data } = await getDataAndId(params);
  if (!data) {
    notFound();
  }
  return
<Suspense>
 <Details data={data} params={params} />
</Suspense>
}
export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const { data } = await getDataAndId(params);

  return {
    title: data?.meta_title ? data?.meta_title : data?.title,
    description: data?.meta_description,
    openGraph: {
      url: `https://myweb.com${
        params?.locale !== "ae" ? "/" + params?.locale : ""
      }/${data?.url}`,
      images: data?.image_url,
      locale: "en_US",
      type: "article",
      title: data?.meta_title ? data?.meta_title : data?.title,
      description: data?.meta_description,
      site_name: "myweb",
    },
    alternates: {
      canonical: `https://myweb.com${
        params?.locale !== "ae" ? "/" + params?.locale : ""
      }/${data?.url}`,
    },
    meta: [
      { name: "author", content: "myweb" },
      { name: "keywords", content: data?.keywords },
    ],
    metadataBase: new URL("https://myweb.com"),
  };
}

export default page;


and Loading.js
import React from "react";

function loading() {
  return <div>loading....</div>;
}

export default loading;


i keep both file on same folder.
If i remove MetaData and wrap the details page in Suspense, it'll work but with MetaData it is not working.
also getDataAndId() hit multiple times when show data and set metadata, that is not good for Performance and it increase the Total blocking time and impact page speed.
